# soundcloud API me/activities waveform_url returns JSON

Tags: soundcloud

I am working with the SoundCloud API and the me/activities endpoint

When examining the data for tracks I was looking at the `waveform_url` data and instead of a .PNG file as indicated in the API reference the data is JSON

Value of the `waveform_url` field is for example :

https://wis.sndcdn.com/S008wsxSkUyp_m.json

I did some research and see that Waveform.js can be used to draw waveforms, but it uses floating point numbers (from their docs):

> ... " an array of floats between 0 and 1"

So the values in the returned data for waveform_url are too large for that.

Any ideas what this data is and how to use it to display a waveform?

This is some of the output:

```
{
   "width":1800,
   "height":140,
   "samples":[
      0,
      99,
      98,
      110,
      95,
      69,
      56,
      50,
      133,
      109,
      134,
      132,

      //...
      //about 250 line skipped

      77,
      71,
      59,
      52,
      46
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The query returns a "width" and a "height" key-value pair wich indicate the dimension of the waveform.

- Width: The number of entries in the list, or the length of the array
- Height: the Max value of all the entries

Using this information you can map each value from the range 0 - height to 0 - 1 and use this as your floating point value to draw a waveform from.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer.

I use the waveform_url to retrieve the json data and then build an array of floating point numbers using (value / height) and then use that with the  waveform.js code